# Checking for presence of Framework 4.6.2 using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have this custom code to check for installation of the Microsoft Framework:

```pascal
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
 IsInstalled: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := '';
  dotNetNeeded := true;

  { Check for required netfx installation }
  { http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#net_b }
  if(Is64BitInstallMode()) then begin
    if (RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release')) then begin
      RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release', IsInstalled);
      if(IsInstalled >= 378675) then begin
        dotNetNeeded := false;
        downloadNeeded := false;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else begin
    if (RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release')) then begin
      RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release', IsInstalled);
      if(IsInstalled >= 378675) then begin
        dotNetNeeded := false;
        downloadNeeded := false;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  if(dotNetNeeded) then begin
    if (not IsAdminLoggedOn()) then begin
      Result := ExpandConstant('{cm:DotNet_NeedAdminRights}');
    end
    else begin
      dotnetRedistPath := ExpandConstant('{src}\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe');
      if not FileExists(dotnetRedistPath) then begin
        dotnetRedistPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe');
        if not FileExists(dotnetRedistPath) then begin
          isxdl_AddFile(dotnetRedistURL, dotnetRedistPath);
          downloadNeeded := true;
        end;
      end;

      if (downloadNeeded) then begin
        if (MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:DotNet_NeedToDownload}'), mbConfirmation, MB_OKCANCEL) = IDCANCEL) then begin
          Result := ExpandConstant('{cm:DotNet_InstallAborted}');
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I am in the process of migrating this code to support the 4.6.2 framework, so I can going to change download path to:

```
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=780600
```

With the file name:

```
NDP462-KB3151800-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe
```

But, it is the registry checking I have a question about. According to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#net_b) for version 4.6.2 the value of the key will be:

> On Windows 10 Anniversary Update: 394802
>
> On all other OS versions: 394806

How do I know within my script which value I should be looking for? Or is it safe to just use `>= 394802`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test for `>= 394802` should be good enough.

If you want to be on the safe side, you use this to test for the Windows 10 Anniversary Update (build 10.0.14393):

```pascal
GetWindowsVersion >= $A003839
```

Comment: Ok. But I do need to support the other OS platforms too which have the lower number. What exactly is the $ prefix number?

Comment: I do not understand. For `GetWindowsVersion >= $A003839` use `394802`. For other versions, use `394806` - The `$xxxx` is a hexadecimal constant.

Comment: So I could actually do two GetWindowsVersion calls to be safe.

Comment: I think I will just test for 394802.